# Redirect to SSL without malforming GET arguments

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I added this to `.htaccess` to redirect HTTP to HTTPS:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

It works, but it malforms GET arguments. For example, a url of `http://example.com/?a=b%20c` turns into `http://example.com/?a=b%2520c`.

How can I fix this rule to keep GET arguments intact?

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Didn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-SSL} !on
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,QSA,L]
```

The $1 is everything in the REQUEST_URI, and the QSA flag will append the existing query string (the GET vars) to the new URL.

Comment: That caused nothing to be redirected...

Comment: That caused nothing to be redirected...